# How to find y coordinate on line B with respective x coordinate of line A

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have two line on graph using `matplotlib` in python

Line `A`

```
A_X = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
A_Y = [33300.0, 32887.6, 33046.4, 33140.9, 32967.8, 32960.0, 33128.95, 33376.95, 33300.0, 33080.0]
```

Line `B` which has first and last point from Line `A` to draw straight line between those points.

```
B_X = [11, 20]
B_Y = [33300.0, 33080.0]
```

So now i want to find all `y` reference coordinates for B_X 12 to B_X 19 `x` coordinate.
Basically from the below image I want to find coordinates for `red` points. Thank you in advance for huge help.

[image: Line A & B]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an interpolation function with [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
line = interp1d(B_X, B_Y)
```

Then choose the X points you want to use for the interpolation and call the interpolation function on them:

```
B_X_points = np.arange(B_X[0], B_X[-1] + 1, 1)
B_Y_points = line(B_X_points)
```

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

A_X = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
A_Y = [33300.0, 32887.6, 33046.4, 33140.9, 32967.8, 32960.0, 33128.95, 33376.95, 33300.0, 33080.0]

B_X = [11, 20]
B_Y = [33300.0, 33080.0]

line = interp1d(B_X, B_Y)
B_X_points = np.arange(B_X[0], B_X[-1] + 1, 1)
B_Y_points = line(B_X_points)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(A_X, A_Y)
ax.plot(B_X_points, B_Y_points, marker = 's', markerfacecolor = 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use linear interpolation with the scipy module:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

f = interp1d(B_X, B_Y)
```

To get the y values for the red points use

```
f(A_X)
```

Coordinates for the red points will be (A_X, f(A_X))